# Deploying AWS Lambda to multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, regions, aws-regions

Quick one.

What does it look like when you’ve got one lambda deployed in multiple regions? Is it just 2 separate copies of the same code with a different name, different ARN etc?

does AWS view them as unrelated lambdas?

Or does it know they’re the same thing deployed in different regions?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot have one Lambda function deployed in multiple regions. If you deployed a piece of code to multiple regions then you've got *multiple* Lambda functions, not one. They might have the same source code but they're not the same Lambda function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two lambda will be treated as separate entities. Sample ARN of lambda

> arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name

Answer (score 0):

AWS does condsider them separate, though the code might be the same. (Imagine college grads testing hello world with same code)
You can still have them as an active-active setup or for fail-over.
Refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-multi-region-serverless-application-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) for more details.